# Do algorithms published in academic journals need to be licensed?

Tags: licensing

I'm looking at creating an implementation of Daugman's iris recognition algorithm, which is covered in his seminal paper on the topic.

What I don't know is, if I implement his algorithm, do I need a license?

Comment: In the U.S., the *algorithm itself* can be protected by patent only. Copyright on the written description of a system does not create a prohibition on the implementation of that system, per [Baker v. Selden](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker_v._Selden): "*whilst no one has a right to print or publish [the author's] book... as a book intended to convey instruction in the art, any person may practice and use the art itself... described and illustrated therein.*" You can't use the author's actual code and you can't use a system protected by patent; anything else is likely fair game.

Comment: Or so goes the conventional wisdom, anyway; I am a legal hobbyist only, not a lawyer. There may be considerable gray area between what is "code" and what is mere "algorithm description".

Answer (score 4):

It may depend on the country you live in. In France algorithms are regarded as ideas and are not subject to copyright, patents, etc. (While the article describing the algorithm or a specific implementation are subject to these.)  So, the short answer to your question is “probably not!”.